# In Rails, how could I programmatically define many complex, related objects and then track user changes to their state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, architecture, rails-activerecord

This might be an unusual situation and a tough question to word, so bear with me.

Let's say I'm representing an enormous house in my Rails app. The house is made up of Rooms and Doors. `Room` and `Door` are my models. The house could have thousands of rooms and doors.

But I -- the developer -- want to predefine all the rooms, doors, and their relationships to each other. I want to define them programmatically, not let users make them. When the app launches, all of these rooms and doors exist. Users can then modify them in some ways, like changing the paint color or locking a door.

So rooms and doors can have state. But the layout of the house is predefined. So are the names of the rooms, and which doors are in a room.

What I'm looking for:

- I write the code and/or markup that defines the rooms and doors, their layout, and their default state. The rooms and doors can all have their own methods and functionality.
- Modifications made to rooms and doors by users -- like locking a door or changing the paint color of a room -- are stored in state (ActiveRecord). This state could be reset by me, the developer, to the default state I built the room or door in.
- I could develop new rooms and doors in the future, releasing them in a new version of the app.

How could I go about achieving something like this?

Comment: Sounds to me like a database consisting of a tables for doors and rooms with an associative relationship (a room has many doors, etc) and the rows in the tables are fixed (you've defined and fixed the number and relationship of doors and rooms by "seediing" the database) and the user can only change attributes of the rows. So in short, a standard Rails app where you disallow create or delete of records.

Comment: @lurker Cool. I didn't know if seeding the database was bad practice, or if there was some sort of tool already build into Rails for doing something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is essentially just an normal application (Rails or any other kind). You define your entities (models), the attributes they have, and the relationships between them. Which kinds of entities users can create/delete versus simply change attributes is a choice you make when you create the user interface.

The question is too broad to cover in detail, but a couple of the things you specifically asked about in Rails terms:

1. You can use the `db/seeds.rb`
   file and `rails db:seed` task to populate your database to a
   specific known state once you've defined your models. Resetting to that state is as simple as dropping the tables and re-running `db:seed`. It's also relatively easy to write scripts/tasks that bulk update data without forcing a complete reset of the database. The same is true for adding additional pre-defined data.
2. When you create routes for your resources (`config/routes.rb`) Rails by default creates routes/actions for all CRUD (CReate/Update/Delete) actions. But, it's simple to override that behaviour and only create the routes/actions that are appropriate for that type:

   ```
   resources :rooms, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for; I knew about restricting resources but I wasn't sure if it was proper practice to seed/update the database in such a way, or if there were mechanics already available in Rails for doing something like that. Turns out there are!